# Symfony/Doctrine: custom find() function

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I want to extend the `Doctrine_core::getTable('table_name')->find('id')` to increment the **table_name.view_count** field each time it is executed. Is this possible?

Comment: Edit the TableNameTable.class.php file, add a find method that increments the view count, and have it call its parent's find method?

Comment: `return parent::find($id) does not work for some reason.

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean?

Comment: It doesn't retrieve any objects.

Comment: What SQL query do you see in the sql tab of the symfony debug toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good practice to put a such functionality into model.